# Datatable activate single cell editing onclick (part 2)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable, inline-editing

Continuing from my previous problem found here:

[Datatable activate single cell editing onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55960355/datatable-activate-single-cell-editing-onclick/56012088#56012088)

I was finally able to get just a single cell to activate an input field onclick.

My new problem is, although I can click on a single cell and activate it, when I use the datatable filter search or go to another page of the datatable, the cell activation no longer works.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'api/searchVoyageInfo.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: '',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data); 
    var table = $('#example1').DataTable({
      "data": jsonObject,
      "columns": [{ 
        { "data": "COLUMN1" },  
        { 
          "data": "COLUMN2",
          "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol)
          {
            $(nTd).html("<a href='#' class='checkBound"+oData.VOYID+"' id='checkBound' 
                         data-uid='"+oData.VOYID+"'>"+oData.COLUMN2+"</a>
                         <input type='text' class='editbound"+oData.VOYID+"' 
                         id='editbound' data-uid='"+oData.VOYID+"' 
                         value='"+oData.BOUND+" display: none;' />");
          }
        },
        { "data": "COLUMN3" },
        // few more columns
      }],
      "iDisplayLength": 50,
      "paging": true,
      "bDestroy": true,
      "autoWidth": true,
      "dom": 'Bfrtip',
       "buttons": [
        // some extend buttons
      ]
    });
  },
  error: function(// some stuff){
    // do some other stuff
    // this part is not important
  }
});
```

If you'll take notice to the COLUMN2 section above, I added a VOYID value to the checkBound class of the href.  I also added the VOYID to the editbound class of the input.  Doing this prevented every single checkBound class from activating the input using the onclick event below:

```
$('#example1').on('click', 'tr > td > a.checkBound', function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable();
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var data = $dataTable.rows().data();
  var rowData = data[tr.index()];

  var voyid = rowData.VOYID;

  console.log(voyid);

  $('.checkBound'+voyid).hide();
  $('.editbound'+voyid).show();
});
```

Using all of the above, on the first page of the datatable, I can successfully activate the input from a single cell onclick.  But it only works on the first page.  I cannot activate the input on any other page.

I tried switching the onclick event from using the class to the id achieving the same results.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure, but I guess `$('#example1').DataTable(…)` probably replaces the element `#example1` with a new one, and that would mean you loose all event handlers bound to that element. Try to apply the event delegation already in use there on a higher level.

Comment: Why the downvote though?

Comment: @04FS - What's weird is, if you'll notice I'm consoling out the voyid.  On the first page, when I activate a cell, the console prints out the id.  The cell fails to activate on any other page, but the console still prints out the id.  If I cannot activate the cell, but the console still prints the ID, how does that affect your initial comment?

Comment: No, if you get the console output, then that wasn’t it. _“I tried switching the onclick event from using the class to the id”_ - you have duplicated the ID `checkBound`, which you must not do, and `a.checkBound` will not match anything, because your links don’t have that class, since you appended the voyid to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the link and show the field with the following code in your click event handler

```
e.preventDefault();
$(this).hide().next().show();
```

Comment: Perfect.  This is what I was looking for.  Thanks, bro.